# How to get locale string in Android dynamically by name?

Tags: android, localization, xamarin.android

I'm using a library that offers a localization interface `ILocalize` which has a method

```
string GetLocale(string constant);
```

On Android I am working with a standard resource file. If the `constant` is "TestString" and my resource file's string would be accessed `r.strings.TestString` - but that obviously only works hardcoded, how can I dynamically get to the string from the `constant` (map from a string constant to an Android string resource ID)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it's so easy to miss it:

```
int resId = context.Resources.GetIdentifier(constant, "string", context.PackageName);
if(resId == 0)
{
    return constant;
}
return context.GetString(resId);
```